# Trouble referencing values from array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a bit of an issue. Right now, as part of a chemistry program, I have:

```
public static Substance Na;
public static Substance Br;

public static Substance NaBr;

public static Substance[][] combinations = {
             {NaBr, NaCl},
         {Na  , Na },
             {Br  , Cl }};
combinations[0][0] = new compound(550);

addCombination(combinations[0][0] , combinations[1][0], combinations[2][0]);
```

The goal here is to add a combination that uses Na and Br to make NaBr. Unfortunately, the program seems be referencing "combinations[1][0]" and "combinations[2][0]" as their own variables instead of the "Na" and "Br" they were meant to reference. If I substitute those values for "Na" and "Br" respectively, it runs like a charm!... any ideas on how to make the array recognized that it is only referencing the pre-initialized "Na" and "Br" instead of the ones in the Array?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code of `addCombination`?

Comment: Please post enough code to see **constructor** for `compound` object and (as was already requested) code of the `addCombination` method.  Also the part that shows the problem in whatever way you discovered it.

Comment: all it does is take three substances. the first parameter it makes the product of all others following it. In this case, the code works if I replace the "combinations[1][0]" and "combinations[2][0]" with "Na" and "Br", So i know that if the array was referencing properly, it would return the same result... or maybe I'm totally missing something...

Comment: Please **post** the code right into your original question instead of describing it.  Sometimes there a big difference between what programmer meant to write and what was actually written.

Answer (score 2):

From your code I can only assume that you have initialized "Na" and "Br" after delcaring

```
public static Substance[][] combinations = {
             {NaBr, NaCl},
             {Na  , Na },
             {Br  , Cl }};
```

If you initalize "Na" and "Br" at the top of your code you will notice that it works fine, because combinations was declared when those 2 variables were not the references do not exist. try this

```
public static Substance Na = new Substance(...);
public static Substance Br = new Substance(...);

public static Substance NaBr = new Substance(...);

public static Substance[][] combinations = {
             {NaBr, NaCl},
         {Na  , Na },
             {Br  , Cl }};
```

and it should work.